# Инструментарий вебразработчика на ubuntu

Tags: веб-программирование, ubuntu

На компе две системы: винда и убунту. Работал в винде, пользовался OpenServer.  Решил перейти на убунту.
Вчера установил xampp, но возникла проблема с обьединением c постгрескл. В убунту не силен. Поставил postgresql - работает.  Поставил phppgadmin - непонятно куда он поставился и как его обьединить с xampp.  И задумался - а нужен ли мне xampp.  Если ставить все пакеты по отдельности, то непонятно что надо ставить, как настраивать. Гугл меня только запутал, ясности не внес.
Склоняюсь, чтобы все по отдельности ставить. Но не хочется тратить неделю на это.  Может где скрипт есть готовый для установки всех компонент?

Посоветуйте, как правильно настроить рабочее место веб-разработчика на убунту? Какие компоненты ставить?

Comment: бро, если ты веб-разработчик, а судя по postgresql ты еще и backend-разработчик, видимо, начинающий, то тебе необходимо знать linux. Загугли курс, или есть хорошая книга: Unix и Linux. Руководство системного администратора

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать docker. Запустил контейнер с нужной версией СУБД (или 10 разных версий любых СУБД без дискомфорта), рядом контейнер с phpMyAdmin или adminer, рядом контейнер с каким-нибудь веб-сервером.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы начали использовать Linux то привыкайте к гуглению.
Файлы настроек обычно хранятся в /etc/ваш_пакет или /var/lib/ваш_пакет. Есть еще пара дерикторий.
Вобщем запросы типа "ubuntu where to find config for phppgadmin" это ваши верные спутники.
https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/how-to-set-up-postgresql-and-phppgadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04-d0db1a0f95f1

По хорошему все такие серверы проще поднимать через докер. Весьмя рекомендую его к изучению.
Книга которую вам посоветовал вам Came Up очень хороша.